# Laravel Guru - How to execute a complicated SQL case statement in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, case

I have got the following SQL query.

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN start_time > end_time AND (CURTIME() > start_time OR CURTIME() < end_time) THEN 'open'
    WHEN start_time < end_time AND (CURTIME() > start_time AND CURTIME() < end_time) THEN 'open'
    ELSE 'closed'
END AS now
FROM user_time;
```

I have to execute it on a Laravel controller. Here is what I have tried.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT CASE
              WHEN start_time > end_time AND (CURTIME() > start_time OR CURTIME() < end_time) THEN 'open'
              WHEN start_time < end_time AND (CURTIME() > start_time AND CURTIME() < end_time) THEN 'open'
              ELSE 'closed'
             END AS NOW_open/closed
            FROM users JOIN user_time;";

$getRestaurant = User::select('users.*','user_time.*', DB::raw($sqlquery));
```

It doesn't work. First of all, the '<' and '>' all turn into &gt and &lt.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Is that a typo in the second query? `WHEN start_time  end_time`. missing the operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi friend you can use **DB::raw** inside select as shown below, Assuming 'start_time' and 'end_time' coming from user_time table

```
User::join('user_time', 'user_time.user_id', '=', users.id)
     ->select(DB::raw('(CASE
         WHEN user_time.start_time > user_time.end_time AND (CURTIME() > user_time.start_time AND CURTIME() < user_time.end_time+24) THEN 'open'
         WHEN user_time.start_time < user_time.end_time AND (CURTIME() < user_time.start_time AND CURTIME() > user_time.end_time) THEN 'open'
         ELSE 'closed'
         END) AS now_open'))->get();
```